# Configuring GlassFish for WS-Security using UsernameToken

Tags: glassfish, ws-security, usernametoken

I am hosting a JAX-WS web service in GlassFish 3.0.1 (Metro stack). I would like to enable WS-Security on this web-service using UsernameTokens. How do I do this? I have not found very good documentation on this subject - much of it is on standalone Metro implementation and seems very complex. In comparison, Apache CXF simply requires an interceptor and a password callback. Can someone direct me to some simple instructions?

Thanks.
Naresh